# Allow angle brackets in logging output with encode wrapper

Tags: java, xml, log4j, log4j2

As part of a web app configuration, there is an XML file that is editable by sysadmins.  For the most part, it is left alone, but there are cases where malformed XML configuration can cause problems.

In my Log4J appender config, I have the following `PatternLayout`

```
<PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{1} - %enc{%msg}%n"/>
```

and a couple strings that include `<$tag></$tag>` in the output to warn the user of a specific missing or invalid property in a XML file.  However, the logging output shows

```
... &lt;$tag&gt;&lt;&#x2F;$tag&gt; tags in $XML.xml are properly defined ...
```

with the above `PatternLayout`.

Is there a way to escape **only** the angle brackets so they show up as expected in the logs?

Comment: Why are you using `%enc`?

Comment: Because one of the future possibilities includes exposing logging info in web console.  Its a feature requested by several sysadmins.

Using `%enc` helps prevent a possible vector of an XSS attack, according to the documentation.

Comment: @Jason So you want to encode it, but not to encode it?

Comment: For specific characters, like angle brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're *telling* it to do that via `%enc{}`:

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html

Specifically:

> &, <, >, ", ', /  Replaced with the corresponding HTML entity

If you have a requirement to view them in a browser, then encode the message on the way to the browser. The logs are your system of record, the views (or the path to the views) should be what change it.

Another solution is to use `equals{pattern}{test}{substitution}` to replace angle brackets. My gut reaction is to not do this; if a system can't view the logs securely, then that system should be responsible for solving that problem–it's a well-known problem with a well-known solution.

Comment: Correct.  Is there a way to escape this for angle brackets or any other character?

Comment: @Jason Using `equals{}{}{}`, but... I'd still do the encoding on the way to the view layer. I might be wrong about this, of course. I'd prefer to log precisely what I think I'm storing, and if a system can't view it securely, fix it in that system.

Comment: Thats about what I figured, but was interested if there was another possibility.